# UIScrollView not working like most scroll views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to make my scroll view get to the bottom of my text without having to 'force scroll'.  So when I scroll down, the scroll bar at the right stops before I reach the bottom portion of the remaining text.  I have to then scroll again with force (so that the scroll bar at the right shrinks, revealing the remaining text).  Hopefully someone has encountered this.  I don't want to force scroll. I want it all displayed in a clean way.

```
UIScrollView *theScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(17.0f, 150.0f, 286.0f, 568.0f)];

label.text = @" a very large portion of text ";

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:16.0];
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[label sizeToFit];
[theScroll setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
theScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(theScroll.contentSize.width, label.frame.size.height);
[theScroll addSubview:label];
[self.view addSubview:theScroll];
```

This is all in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Instead of giving the scroll view a fixed frame, try it with view's frame. e.g.: `initWithFrame:self.view.frame`

Comment: @UditS Actually it should be based on the view's `bounds`, not its `frame`. `initWithFrame:self.view.bounds`. The different becomes clear when the view's origin isn't 0,0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things don't quite seem right.

1. You set the label's `origin.y` to `150`. Did you mean to have the label start so far from the top of the scroll view's content area?
2. You set the scroll view's `contentSize.height` to be the same as the label's height. This conflicts with #1. The `contentSize.height` should be tall enough for all of the content.

Assuming #1 is correct, #2 should be set as:

```
theScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(theScroll.contentSize.width, CGRectGetMaxY(label.frame));
```

Remember, the bottom of the label will be its origin + its height, not just its height.

Comment: Yes, I eventually want to add a title above the label so the 150 leaves just enough space.  And thank you very much , it worked like a charm.  So that makes sense about the origin+height...it always looked like there was a particular gap of space not being shown.